# Disqus - setting disqus_url Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, disqus

No matter what I do, all comments are shown on all pages by the same poster. So if I post "hello" on page 1... it shows on all pages.

So my structure is like this:

```
http://www.example.com/23/some_post
```

I have the identifier as such:

```
var disqus_identifier = "66";// set via php
var disqus_url = "http://www.example.com/23/some_post";
```

No change.

I've tried this too (link: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/disqus-dev/hi8mm5DtN-s)

```
DISQUS.reload({
  reload: true,
  config: function () {
    this.page.identifier = "66";
    this.page.url = "http://www.example.com/23/some_post";
  }
});
```

Here's what I traced the problem to:

setting the "disqus_url" lets say of http://www.example.com/23/some_post shows the url inside the Admin > Discussions box as http://www.example.com/23

In other words, the url is truncated. **But here is the really odd thing: IF I set the url with a colon at the end or in it, such as http://www.example.com/23/some_post: then it doesn't truncate it anymore.**

I have no idea why this madness is happening. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Did you fixed this problem? I have it too.